# SignalR webapp under IIS7.5 don't works on Firefox access from other webapp(cross-domain)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, iis-7.5, signalr

I'm testing the SignalR(1.1.0) Chat sample under IIS 7.5.

I'm, trying to connect from a diferent webapp to my SignalR webapp(cross-domain).

I have made the cross-domain configuration at my web.config, this works fine in the asp.net development server, and had enable the cors on global.asax.

But, when I deploy this project to IIS 7.5, this don't work. Then I notice that it only works in IE 8, not in Firefox.

I made the connection as follow:

```
        var connection = $.hubConnection('http://my.webserver.ip/sincronismoSR'),
            chatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('chatHub');

        connection.start().done(function() {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                chatHubProxy.invoke('Send', $('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
```

I have look at the request made, it get a 200 response, but the answer was empty.

Comment: When you say you enabled cors in your Global.asax does that mean you did the EnableCrossDomain flag set in your MapHubs call?

Comment: yes, I'm refer to this configuration, I'll change my question so it's more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, but I don't understand why, when I'm using the Firefox it don't choose the right transport if I didn't set.

```
    var connection = $.hubConnection('http://my.webserver.ip/sincronismoSR'),
        chatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('chatHub');

    connection.start({ transport: ['webSockets', 'longPolling'] }).done(function() {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
            chatHubProxy.invoke('Send', $('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
            $('#message').val('').focus();
        });
    });
```

So, this `{ transport: ['webSockets', 'longPolling'] }` configuration fixed my issue.

Comment: You can probably just have longpling if you want to since there will never be websockets with SignalR without IIS8 .NET4.5 and win8/2012server

Comment: for me this is the worst problem of M$, we have support only if we keep buying,keep buying,keep buying...

Comment: In this particular case I do not think that MS idea is to sell more hardware. They just took a shortcut using websockets as a OS feature instead of doing a cross platform implementation

Comment: No, This is the M$ strategy to sell more software.

Comment: @Uffe this I still using those two transport alternatives, because I have a big and new production env come in.

Answer (score 5):

Claudio, We were using SignalR in a project and it worked really well. Unfortunatelly I did not do my research good enough. I thought that SignalR was websockets when the browser supported it, but the thruth was that we never had websockets since we were running .NET 4.0 on 2008 R2 server.

SignalR websocket transport require .NET 4.5, IIS8, 2012Server/Win8 and that is not acceptable for our project (yet).

I looked around and found a few alternatives on the .NET stack. Finally we decided to use xsockets.NET (http://xsockets.net) and have not  looked back since.
It was really easy to move from SignalR to xsockets and xsockets has websocket support on ALL platforms. Also supports Mono.

The thing that woke us up was the comparison between signalr and xsocket: http://xsockets.net/xsockets-vs-signalr

No shadow on SignalR though. It is a good alternative but not suitable for us due to server requirements. Just to bad that the community seems to think SignalR is realtime all the time. But as I said we only have our selves to blame since we did not read the docs good enough and watsed lots of hours :(

Best of luck

Comment: +1 Awesome post, I didn't know that I have another alternatives. Thanks